# how to stop wordpress hosted on iis from encoding and decoding images that contains arabic characters

Tags: wordpress, iis, urlencode

I have a wordpress website that I deployed on IIS the website had a problem earlier that arabic names for posts and categories was not working and after a lot of search I found an answer on stackoverflow that advice me to add those two lines in my wp-config.php file

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];}
```

and thankfully it works for posts and categories , but the same problem is still happen in images in arabic and all these images are not shown in my website

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your WordPress page contains below code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Below is an example of HTML page:

[image]

[image]